# Consolidate karate-summary report

Tags: karate

We recently made some updates to our runners, to combine multiple runs into a single Test

```
package net.equipment.runners;

import java.io.File;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class EquipmentRunner_AllInOne {

    private static final String serviceName = "EquipmentService";
    private static final String reportRoot = "target/" + serviceName + "/";
    private static final String dtStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1 v1 = new _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1()
                .reportDir(reportRoot + dtStamp + "/domain/v1")
                .buildDir(reportRoot + dtStamp);
        v1.concatRunner();

        _EquipmentRunnerDomainV2 v2 = new _EquipmentRunnerDomainV2()
                .reportDir(reportRoot + dtStamp + "/domain/v2")
                .buildDir(reportRoot + dtStamp);
        v2.concatRunner();

        // _EquipmentRunnerDomainV3 v3 = new _EquipmentRunnerDomainV3()
        // .reportDir(reportRoot + dtStamp + "/domain/v3")
        // .buildDir(reportRoot + dtStamp);
        // v3.concatRunner();

        // _EquipmentRunnerDomainV4 v4 = new _EquipmentRunnerDomainV4()
        // .reportDir(reportRoot + dtStamp + "/domain/v4")
        // .buildDir(reportRoot + dtStamp);
        // v4.concatRunner();

        // _EquipmentRunnerGraph graph = new _EquipmentRunnerGraph()
        // .reportDir(reportRoot + dtStamp + "/graph")
        // .buildDir(reportRoot + dtStamp);
        // Graph.concatRunner();

        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(reportRoot + dtStamp), new String[] { "json" }, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), serviceName);
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

and

```
package net.equipment.runners;

import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1 {

    private static final String serviceName = "EquipmentService";
    private static final String reportRoot = "target/" + serviceName + "/";
    private static final Integer cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    public String _path = "classpath:net/equipment/test/api/domain/v1";
    public String[] _tags = { "@regression", "@hopper" };
    public String _karateEnv = "dev";
    public String _buildDir = reportRoot + "/";
    public String _reportDir = reportRoot + "/domain/v1";

    public _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1() {
    }

    public _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1 path(String _path) {
        this._path = _path;
        return this;
    }

    public _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1 tags(String[] _tags) {
        this._tags = _tags;
        return this;
    }

    public _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1 karateEnv(String _karateEnv) {
        this._karateEnv = _karateEnv;
        return this;
    }

    public _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1 buildDir(String _buildDir) {
        this._buildDir = _buildDir;
        return this;
    }

    public _EquipmentRunnerDomainV1 reportDir(String _reportDir) {
        this._reportDir = _reportDir;
        return this;
    }

    // Allows concatenated execution of runner
    @Test
    public void concatRunner() {
        Results results = Runner
                .path(_path)
                .tags(_tags)
                .karateEnv(_karateEnv)
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .outputHtmlReport(true)
                .outputJunitXml(true)
                .buildDir(_buildDir)
                .reportDir(_reportDir)
                .systemProperty("karate.dsRow", "1") 
                .parallel(cores);

        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }

    // Allows manual execution of runner with results
    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner
                .path("classpath:net/equipment/test/api/domain/v1")
                .tags("@regression", "@hopper")
                .karateEnv(_karateEnv)
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .outputHtmlReport(true)
                .outputJunitXml(true)
                .reportDir(_reportDir)
                .systemProperty("karate.dsRow", "1") 
                .parallel(cores);

        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] { "json" }, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), serviceName);
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

This works great to execute multiple runners with a single test or mvn command.  This also consolidates all the tests into a single cucumber report, however the karate reports are tied to each single runner.  Before we start manipulating the source code or building a custom reporting methodology, would it be possible to separate the generate report function(s) for the karate reports, from the actual test runs, similar to the cucumber reports, or provide a method to consolidate all the summary reports, from subdirectories into a parent directory?

Comment: that sounds like a good thing to do. it will require refactoring of the `Suite` class: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.0/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Suite.java - you can open a feature request, but right now I can't give an ETA

Comment: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2337